# Tubular heater placement in garage

Tags: heating, garage, heater

I've purchased a 4ft tubular thermostatic heater for my garage to hopefully keep the frost/moisture at bay.

I have two options to install it either at the top or the wall near the roof, or near the floor.

**Where would be the best place to install it to get the best use out of it?**

(My garage roof is insulated but the walls are not, if that makes any difference)

[image: Tubular heater]

Comment: What's the make/model of this? Is it a radiant heater, or does it heat the air? How much are you thinking to raise the garage's temperature?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a radiant (quartz tube) heater, a high mount will keep it out of the way, but be sure to install an air-spaced reflector to keep it from starting a fire in the wall.

If it is a convection heater, it must be mounted low. Again, be sure that the installation meets fire and electrical codes.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal with this heater? Your comfort? If so, it's important to keep it close to you. There are two ways that heat moves: radiation and convection. The radiation range on that thing is only a few feet, so you'll need to be close to it to get any comfort from it. And convection from a heat source that small isn't going to heat your garage quickly no matter where you put it.

For safety sake, don't mount it somewhere something might fall on it or touch it, so that probably means above head level. Maybe above your work bench pointed down?

Also, for safety sake, put it on a timer that runs no longer than 30 minutes and does not have a bypass or On setting. That way if you forget to turn it off, it will turn itself off and hopefully not burn down your house!